# Postgres bytea data retrieved is different from what I inserted

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express

I have a react front end that can post data into a postgres back end using express. I uploaded a pdf file that is 779 bytes in size as a byte array (U8intArray) from the front end using javascript's FileReader(). The bytes get inserted into my database's table column of type bytea.

When FileReader() runs, my app logs the file's data buffer to the console. The console shows that the file has the following starting bytes:

```js
(779)[37, 80, 68, 70, 45, 49, 46, ... ]
```

I can verify that these bytes are indeed stored into my database using this sql query from the terminal:

```sql
select left(encode(my_file, 'escape'), 50) from apps where id = 24;
```

Terminal output:

```
left                        
----------------------------------------------------
{"0":37,"1":80,"2":68,"3":70,"4":45,"5":49,"6":46,
(1 row)
```

But here's the problem: When my front end tries to retrieve this byte array data from postgress, the bytes look different from the what I inserted:

```js
// the id used is 24
axios.get("/api/get/app", { params: { id } }).then((res) => {
  console.log(res.data.my_file.data);
})
```

Console output:

```
(7136)[123, 34, 48, 34, 58, 51, 55, ... ]
```

it has 7136 bytes. I expected the original [37, 80, 68, 70, 45, 49, 46, ... ] with 779 total bytes.

And when I retrieve a different pdf data from a different row, the console will output a similar array that again starts with the same [123, 34, 48, 34, 58, 51, 55, ... ] as in the previous attempt, but with a different total number of bytes, like 147990.

I am using the same post/get request structure as with other types of data like strings and numbers which work fine from the front end. But with bytea data, the output that comes back to the front end is not the same as what I put in. There must be some change of format when I retrieve a bytea data.

**So the question is, how can I retrieve the bytea data that I inserted and turn it into the original Uint8Array format?**

As for the code, my database has a table called apps that stores job application data fields. Its columns include things like the company name, application date, and resume.

```js
  //front end code to retrieve data from database
  const { id } = useParams();
  const context = useContext(Context);
  const [postingURL, setPostingURL] = useState("");
  const [companyName, setCompanyName] = useState("");
  const [jobTitle, setJobTitle] = useState("");
  const [jobDescription, setJobDescription] = useState("");
  const [jobNotes, setJobNotes] = useState("");
  const [tags, setTags] = useState("");
  const [appDate, setAppDate] = useState();
  const [elapsedDays, setElapsedDays] = useState(0);
  const [careersList, setCareersList] = useState([""]);
  const [careerNum, setCareerNum] = useState(0);
  const [newCareerNum, setNewCareerNum] = useState();
  const [resumeBytea, setResumeBytea] = useState();
  const [coverLetterBytea, setCoverLetterBytea] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (context.isAuthenticated && context.dbProfileState) {
      axios
        .get("/api/get/app", { params: { id } })
        .then((res) => {
          setPostingURL(res.data.posting_url);
          setCompanyName(res.data.company_name);
          setJobTitle(res.data.job_title);
          setJobDescription(res.data.job_description);
          setJobNotes(res.data.job_notes);
          setTags(String(res.data.tags));
          setCareerNum(
            newCareerNum >= 0
              ? newCareerNum
              : dbProfile.careers_list.indexOf(res.data.career_name)
          );
          let appDate = new Date(res.data.application_date);
          let currDate = new Date();
          let elapsed =
            Math.ceil((currDate - appDate) / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) - 1;
          setAppDate(appDate);
          setElapsedDays(elapsed);
          setResumeBytea(res.data.resume_file)
          // console.log(res.data.resume_file)
          setCoverLetterBytea(res.data.cover_letter_file.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
  }, [context, id]);

}
```

```js
//back end express/node code to send table row data to front end 
router.get("/api/get/app", (req, res) => {
  const appId = req.query.id;
  pool.query(
    `SELECT * FROM apps WHERE app_id = $1`,
    [appId],
    (q_err, q_res) => {
      res.json(q_res.rows[0]);
    }
  );
  console.log("Queried row id:", appId);
});
```

Table structure:

```js
CREATE TABLE apps (
  app_id SERIAL UNIQUE,
  username TEXT UNIQUE REFERENCES users(username),
  career_name TEXT,
  posting_url TEXT,
  company_name TEXT NOT NULL,
  job_title TEXT NOT NULL,
  job_description TEXT,
  job_notes TEXT,
  resume_file BYTEA, 
  cover_letter_file BYTEA,
  tags TEXT [],
  application_date TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY(app_id)
);
```

Comment: how is `my_file.data` produced on the server? Can you share the code that produces it?

Comment: Oluwafemi Sule, I edited my original post to address your question. Does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

The bytea data in postgres is in binary format and you need to encode it into text format from the back end before sending it.

So instead of sending the whole row using the `SELECT *` sql query like this:

```
router.get("/api/get/app", (req, res) => {
  const appId = req.query.id;
  pool.query(
    `SELECT * FROM apps WHERE app_id = $1`,
    [appId],
    (q_err, q_res) => {
      res.json(q_res.rows[0]);
    }
  );
  console.log("Queried row id:", appId);
});
```

I had to modify the sql query to use the [encode()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-binarystring.html) function like this:

```sql
SELECT app_id, username, career_name, posting_url, company_name, job_title, 
    job_description, job_notes, encode(resume_file::bytea, 'escape') as "resume_file", encode(cover_letter_file::bytea, 'escape') as "cover_letter_file", tags, application_date FROM apps WHERE app_id = $1
```

Then the front end will receive the resolved data object "res" where the res.data.resume_file part of the row data will be a string like this:

```
'{"0":37,"1":80,"2":68,"3":70,"4":45,"5":49,"6":46, ...}'
```

Then you need to JSON.parse() it into an object, then turn it into an array, then into a Uint8Array like this:

```
const resumeData = JSON.parse(res.data.resume_file);
let resumeByteA = Object.keys(resumeData).map((key) => resumeData[key]);
resumeByteA = new Uint8Array(resumeByteA);
```